# Azure Function cannot connect Event Hub via Virtual network

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventhub

The following code described bellow cannot connect to my Event Hub using Managed Identity and a separate VNet sub-net (please look into my Function and Event Hub settings)

PS: It`s possible to connect the Event Hub in case I temporary switch off the 'Selected networks' and turn on the 'Public access' and return it back for my Event Hub settings.

Additional Info: My Azure Function code is run as a Linux docker container and exposes the following ports: 80, 443, and for AMQP connection 5671, 5672

```
const string ServiceBusNamespacePostfix = ".servicebus.windows.net"

var fullyQualifiedNamespace = eventHubSettings.Value.NameSpace.Contains(ServiceBusNamespacePostfix)
                ? eventHubSettings.Value.NameSpace
                : $"{eventHubSettings.Value.NameSpace}{ServiceBusNamespacePostfix}";

_producerClient = new Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Producer.EventHubProducerClient(fullyQualifiedNamespace, eventHubSettings.Value.Name, credential,
                new EventHubProducerClientOptions
                {
                    ConnectionOptions = new EventHubConnectionOptions
                    {
                        TransportType = EventHubsTransportType.AmqpTcp,
                    }
                }
            );
```

Azure Function settings:
[image]

Event Hub settings:
[image]

Please could anyone suggest what should I correct into the code and if my settings are wrong or I don`t understand VNet`s usage correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The Vnet configuration appears to be correct. Please try to add the following app settings to the Function configuration and check if the issue is resolved.

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER | 168.63.129.16 |
| WEBSITE_CONTENTOVERVNET | 1 |

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#website_contentovervnet

Please let me know the outcome. I will be able to assist you further.

Answer (score 0):

Good day.
Unfortunately, the suggestion above did not help and was not working. However, it has started working well after adding a new private link/endpoint as the connection between my Azure Function and the Even Hub.

Comment: This should be a comment on that answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).